# choose values of variable in effect function - R

Tags: r

```
sub <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9,10,10,11,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,15,15,16,16,17,17,18,18,19,19,20,20)
f1 <- c("f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","f","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m","m")
f2 <- c("c1","c1","c1","c1","c1","c1","c1","c1","c1","c1","c2","c2","c2","c2","c2","c2","c2","c2","c2","c2","c1","c1","c1","c1","c1","c1","c1","c1","c1","c1","c2","c2","c2","c2","c2","c2","c2","c2","c2","c2")
f3 <- c(0.03,0.03,0.49,0.49,0.33,0.33,0.20,0.20,0.13,0.13,0.05,0.05,0.47,0.47,0.30,0.30,0.22,0.22,0.15,0.15, 0.03,0.03,0.49,0.49,0.33,0.33,0.20,0.20,0.13,0.13,0.05,0.05,0.47,0.47,0.30,0.30,0.22,0.22,0.15,0.15)
y <- c(0.9,1,98,96,52,49,44,41,12,19,5,5,89,92,65,56,39,38,35,33, 87,83,5,7,55,58,67,61,70,80,88,90,0.8,0.9,55,52,55,58,70,69)

dat <- data.frame(sub=sub, f1=f1, f2=f2, f3=f3, y=y)

m <- lmer(y ~ f1*f2*f3 + (1|sub), data=dat)


library(effects)
fit <- effect('f1:f3', m)
fit_df <- as.data.frame(fit)

   f1   f3       fit       se     lower     upper
1   f 0.03  1.908931 4.440515 -7.136102  10.95396
2   m 0.03 93.323001 4.440515 84.277968 102.36803
3   f 0.10 15.972474 3.530700  8.780673  23.16428
4   m 0.10 80.567822 3.530700 73.376022  87.75962
5   f 0.30 56.154027 2.827934 50.393713  61.91434
6   m 0.30 44.124456 2.827934 38.364143  49.88477
7   f 0.40 76.244803 3.846031 68.410694  84.07891
8   m 0.40 25.902774 3.846031 18.068664  33.73688
9   f 0.50 96.335579 5.254148 85.633229 107.03793
10  m 0.50  7.681091 5.254148 -3.021259  18.38344
```

This will create a data frame with arbitrary `f3` values (in the example `0.03, 0.10, 0.30, 0.40, 0.50`). But what if I want to choose the values myself (say `0.04, 0.20, 0.50`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `xlevels`

```
library(effects)

fit <- effect('f1:f3', m, xlevels=list(f3 = c(0.04, .2, .5)))
fit_df <- as.data.frame(fit)


#  f1   f3       fit       se     lower     upper
#1  f 0.04  3.918009 4.301342 -4.843539  12.67956
#2  m 0.04 91.500832 4.301342 82.739285 100.26238
#3  f 0.20 36.063251 2.687348 30.589301  41.53720
#4  m 0.20 62.346139 2.687348 56.872190  67.82009
#5  f 0.50 96.335579 5.254148 85.633229 107.03793
#6  m 0.50  7.681091 5.254148 -3.021259  18.3834
```